# Can not create root Site Collection

Tags: permissions

I Get Error while creating Site Collection in sharepoint 2013 with spadmin account. previosly it was working fine.

Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

when you see the site collections in view, site collection deosnt appear too.

What can be the issue?

custom webpart or features can cause such issues ?

Comment: did you check the uls logs for more info about the error? root site means 1st site in web application "/"?

Comment: Yes..Nothng significant in ULS logs

Comment: Can you try to create the sitecollection from powershell instead and see if that works? new-spsite.

Comment: did you apply any recent updates to farm? what farm level?

Comment: What farm level means?

Comment: i am sorry...i mean what farm version level? how many servers in farm? and any changes to farm recently?

Comment: one more thing is, i am able to create site collection through powershell but not through CA. publishing portal can be created succesfully through CA but not team site collection

Comment: And you could create a site collection with powershell using the team site template? (STS#0) ?

Comment: Yes. i can create using powershell